# Given table, what could be the value of the integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

The table below gives selected values of a continuous function $f$. If $f$ is increasing over the closed interval $[0,3]$ which of the following could be the value of $\int^{3}_{0} f(x)dx  $?

The table given is:

```
x:    0   .5   1   1.5   2   2.5   3
f(x): 0   4   10   18   28   40   54
```

Narrowing down the answers, I determined that the integral must be less than $77$, since that is the maximum sum of the Reimann sum, if the function was not always increasing.

However, the last two choices are $50$ or $62$. Why is $50$ an impossibility?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int^{3}_{0} f(x)dx=\int^{0.5}_{0} f(x)dx+\int^{3}_{0.5} f(x)dx$$
You can easily obtain by summing :
$$\int^{3}_{0.5} f(x)dx\geq 50$$
But $f(0.5)=4$ and $f$ is continuous, so $\exists a \in (0,0.5) $ such that on $[a,0.5],f>0$. Furthermore $f\geq0$ on $[0,0.5]$ since $f$ is increasing so :
$$\int^{0.5}_{0} f(x)dx>0$$
Finally :
$$\int^{3}_{0} f(x)dx>50$$

Comment: You don't really need to split it up in two integrals. The total integral is between $50$ and $77$ using that $f$ is increasing, and strictly between those bounds using that $f$ is continuous.